# Postgresql and Web application on a single core

Tags: postgresql, linode

There are case Postgres will insert new record into table each time user visit every pages, will Postgres be slow if web application use >98% of the CPU usage for incoming requests or what can be improve RPS in Linode VPS 1 cpu core on Ubuntu 15?

Or are there anything wrong with the created table?

```
CREATE TABLE "mysession"
"token" varchar NOT NULL,
"username" varchar,
"created" int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
"updated" int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
"idle" int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
PRIMARY KEY ("token") NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE ) WITH (OIDS=FALSE);
```

Comment: Have you profiled this and determined that the database activity is the bottleneck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL is not likely to be a bottleneck on CPU for INSERTS. If it is you may consider

- turning on asynchronous_commits.
- disabling wal_logs

There other [options as well that are documented in the Non-Durable Settings](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/non-durability.html) doc.

Comment: Or are there anything wrong with the created table shown in my edited question?

Comment: `WITH (OIDS=FALSE);` is old and the default.. username and token should probably be text and not varchar, created/updated sounds like they should be timestamps.